# Calculating the class group of $\mathcal{O}_K$, for $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

How to calculate the class group of $\mathcal{O}_K$, for $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$ without using the Minkowski bound?

Comment: I'm not sure the reason for the down vote, but maybe I'm overly partial to all class group questions.  I'm interested to know:  why do you not want to use the Minkowski bound?  I guess you could show that it is a norm-Euclidean domain, for example.  Or use the class number formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p\not=2$ a prime number.
Since $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=2$, then happens one of the cases:

1) $(p)=\mathfrak{p}$,

2) $(p)=\mathfrak{p}^2$ or

3) $(p)=\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{q}$,

where $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ are prime ideals;

If $\left(\frac{7}{p}\right)=-1$, then $(p)$ is prime in $\mathcal{O}_K$. If $\left(\frac{7}{p}\right)=1$, then exists $1\leq x\leq \frac{p-1}{2}$  s.t. $x^2-7=pn$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. But
$
|x^2-7|\leq x^2+7\leq \frac{(p-1)^2}{4}+7
$
 and 
$$
pn\leq \frac{(p-1)^2}{4}+7< p^2 \Longleftrightarrow p\geq 3.
$$
But $(p)=(p,x+\sqrt{7})(p,x-\sqrt{7})$ and since $(x+\sqrt{7})\subset \mathfrak{p}=(p,x+\sqrt{7})$, exists ideal $I$ s.t. $(x+\sqrt{7})= \mathfrak{p}I$. Thus
$$
p^2>pn=x^2-7=N(x+\sqrt{7})=N(\mathfrak{p})N(I)=pN(I),
$$
then $N(I)<p$.

In this case, using induction, $Cl(K)$ is generated by prime ideals $\mathfrak{q}$ s.t. $\mathfrak{q}\cap \mathbb{Z}=2\mathbb{Z}$.

Furthermore, $(2)=(2,1+\sqrt{7})^2$ and $(2,1+\sqrt{7})=(3+\sqrt{7})$. Then, $|Cl(K)|=1$.

Comment: @JohnM, I tried to explain.

Answer (score 5):

1. You could show it is a [norm-Euclidean domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain).  If so, this would show the field has class number 1.
2. You could use the [*class number formula*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_formula), either in its general form or its special form for real quadratic fields, called the *Dirichlet class number formula*.  This will get you the class number, but not the class group per se.  But if the class number is 1 or prime, then you'll know the class group too.

Mathematicians think that it is likely that about 3/4 of the real quadratic fields have class number 1, so you can make an educated guess about what the class number likely is.

Answer (score 2):

Put another way, as there is no solution to $x^2 - 7 y^2 = -1$ or $x^2 - 7 y^2 = -4,$ we identify the indefinite quadratic forms $x^2 - 7 y^2$ with $-x^2 + 7 y^2$ to collapse two form equivalence classes into one field class. This is the Lagrange-Gauss cycle method for equating binary forms. Reduced forms $\langle a,b,c \rangle,$ meaning $f(x,y) = a x^2 + b xy+ c y^2,$ are precisely those with $b^2 - 4 a c = \Delta,$ here $\Delta = 28,$ then $ac < 0$ and $b > |a+c|.$

---

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefReduced
               2           2          -3
              -2           2           3
               3           2          -2
              -3           2           2
               1           4          -3
              -1           4           3
               3           4          -1
              -3           4           1
    jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle 1 4 -3

  0  form              1           4          -3


           1           0
           0           1

To Return  
           1           0
           0           1

0  form   1 4 -3   delta  -1
1  form   -3 2 2   delta  1
2  form   2 2 -3   delta  -1
3  form   -3 4 1   delta  4
4  form   1 4 -3


  form   1 x^2  + 4 x y  -3 y^2 

minimum was   1rep   x = 1   y = 0 disc   28 dSqrt 5.2915026221  M_Ratio  28
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
2  9
3  14
=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle 3 4 -1

  0  form              3           4          -1


           1           0
           0           1

To Return  
           1           0
           0           1

0  form   3 4 -1   delta  -4
1  form   -1 4 3   delta  1
2  form   3 2 -2   delta  -1
3  form   -2 2 3   delta  1
4  form   3 4 -1


  form   3 x^2  + 4 x y  -1 y^2 

minimum was   1rep   x = 0   y = 1 disc   28 dSqrt 5.2915026221  M_Ratio  3.111111
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
2  3
9  14
=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

---